# Jquery ajax context is not working as intended

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to execute and display ajax request.
Here, I want to inject the ajax returened html into the mainCanvas. Tried context to "`this`" but not working. Can you please share some idea?

also I dont want to set the context to "`this.mainCanvas`" because I have to inject html in other elements as well.

```
    var RequestController = {
            mainCanvas: $("#mainCanvas"),   
            panelCanvas: $("#subDiv"),
            Start:function(){
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://myserverurl.com",
                    context: this,
                    success:function(data){
                        this.mainCanvas.html(data);
                    }
                });
            }
    };
```

Comment: I'd say setting context to `this` sets the context to the `start` function - and `mainCanvas` is not available within that context.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, that's why I'm not posing an answer. You can try setting the context to `RequestController` and see what happens.

Comment: Aleks G, Are you sure. Its not what you are saying. I already tried that

Comment: var Box={current:0;next:function(){this.current++}}//Its a working piece from my code. See the this.current

Comment: No, I'm not sure, as I stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your are trying to put html in dive before it is rendred. Always inject html when the  DOM is fullly loaded. You might check this within the `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
   created: function() {
    var vueInstance = this;
    $.ajax({
    url: urls.api.getStates,
    context: vueInstance,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (response) {
        $.each(response, function (stateCodeId, name) {
            var stateObj = new Object();
            stateObj.id = stateCodeId;
            stateObj.name = name;
            vueInstance.states.push(stateObj);
        });
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
        $('#errorMsg').show();
        $("#errorMsg").focus();
        this.ErrorHeader = "Error(s)";
        this.ErrorMessage = "<li>An error occurred while retrieving the list of schools. Please try again later.</li>";
    }
})
}
```

Just spent a solid half hour dealing with this problem, I know the thread is old but I hope this helps someone!

Comment: This doesn't really solve the problem. It just bypasses context entirely, and the point is to be able to use `this` within the success callback

Comment: yea but the issue is that your scope has changed, this has been over ridden by ajax object because the context has changed. how are you to determine between when you want ajax's version of "this" vs vues version of "this"?

Comment: that's a fair point in general but in the question, it doesn't appear that he will be needing to switch between having to use ajax and VueInstance. He just needs the VueInstance in success callback, accessible with `this`.

Comment: @OzzyTheGiant i think the only real way to solve this is to use Es Next or typescript as they handle scoping better then vanilla js + jquery.

Answer (score 0):

use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

```
var RequestController = {
    mainCanvas : $("#mainCanvas"),
    panelCanvas : $("#subDiv"),
    Start : function() {
        $.ajax({
                    url : "http://myserverurl.com",
                    context : this,
                    success : $.proxy(function(data) {
                                this.mainCanvas.html(data);
                            }, this)
                });
    }
};
```